# Displaying a JTable without vertical and horizontal scroll bars but showing all the rows and columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

This is what I have : a Jframe consisting of a JTabbedPane ( besides other elements). The JTabbedPane contains a JScrollPane as one of its tabs. The JScrollPane has a JPanel. Within the JPanel, a number of JLabel's and JTable's are to be displayed. I have created the GUI using NetBeans drag and drop Swing editor.

Each of the JTable is contained within a JScrollPane. ( which the IDE has inserted ) Right now, the height of the JTable is fixed. So, if the number of elements are less, empty space is displayed within the JScrollPane. If the number of elements are more, the user needs to scroll the JScrollPane which contains the JTable. The same is the case with horizontal scroll of the JTable. If the window is maximized, the JTable's width also increases to occupy the entire available area. Is it possible to modify the GUI so that the height of the JScrollPane becomes as large as necessary to display all the rows of the JTable without scrolling? And the width of the JTable should be as large as required to show the contents without horizontal scroll. If the number of columns in the JTable's are too many or if the number of elements ( JTable's and JLabel's ) in the JPanel ( of the JScrollPane of JTabbedPane ) are too many, then the scrolling through items will be done through the scrollbar of the JScrollPane ( of the JTabbedPane )

Comment: Don't add it to a scroll pane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer For that do I need to do changes to the code or can I do it through the NetBeans Swing GUI Editor itself?

Comment: You can change it through the editor, but you'll need to remove the tables from the scroll panes and delete the scroll panes. This will also remove the column headers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use a JTable is to add the table to a JScrollPane so that the table header also appears. What you need to do is set the scrollpanes size to the size of the table so that you can see all the data and don't see the scrollbars. The code would be:

```
JTable table = new JTable( ... );
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

Now if the layout manager of your panel respects the preferred size of the scrollpane you will see all the data of the table.

Of course if you dynamically change data in the table then the preferred size will change so the better solution is to override the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(...)` of the table to return the appropriate value.

The other approach is to use a panel with a BorderLayout. Add the table header to the NORTH and the table to the CENTER then add the panel to your tabbed pane.